# Removing a value from a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP I'm trying to remove an element from an array based on the value of the element.

For example with the following array:

```
Array
(
    [671] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 1000
        )
    [900] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 88
        }
)
```

I'd like to be able to specify a value of on of the inner arrays to remove.  For example if I specified 100 the resulting array would look like:

```
Array
(
    [671] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [2] => 1000
        )
    [900] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 88
        }
)
```

My first thought was to loop through the array using foreach and unset the "offending" value when I found it, but that doesn't seem to reference the original array, just the loop variables that were created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($array as $id => $data){
    foreach($data as $index => $offending_val){
         if($offending_val === 100){
            unset($array[$id][$index]);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
array_walk($your_array, function(&$sub, $key, $remove_value) {
    $sub = array_diff($sub, array($remove_value));
}, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

Couple of ideas:

You could try array_filter, passing in a callback function that returns false if the value is the one you want to unset. Using your example above:

$new_inner_array = array_filter($inner_array, $callback_that_returns_false_if_value_100)

If you want to do something more elaborate, you could explore the ArrayIterator class of the SPL, specifically the offsetUnset() method.